# Standing waves in Maple

Tags: maple

How do I create The following in three dimensions? (one more extra dimension to what I already have)

```
with(plots):

animate(sin(Pi*(t-x))*Heaviside(t-x)-sin(Pi*(t+x))*Heaviside(t+x),x=-6..0,t=-5.99..12,frames=200,numpoints=200,color=red);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `plots[animate]` command. Something like the following:

```
plots[animate](plot3d, [sin(Pi*(t-x))*Heaviside(t-x)-sin(Pi(t+x))*Heaviside(t+x), x = -6 .. 0, y = -6 .. 0], t = -5.99 .. 12, frames = 200, numpoints = 200, color = red, orientation = [75, 75, 0])
```